# Checkbox Issue- Cannot set properties of null (setting 'checked')

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, checkbox

Good day everyone, I am currently facing some issues with my following code. Basically I want to keep my checkbox checked by using the key value pair value I stored in localStorage, so upon reload the checkbox should be checked (those with the key value pair). However, I kept getting this error.
I have tried using window.onLoad but it did not work; any other solutions for this..? Please do let me know if there is anything wrong with my code too. Thank you

Error

```
Cannot set properties of null (setting 'checked')
```

Html Code:

```
<div style="color: #005e95">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxFullDownload" data-dojo-attach-event="onClick: _test" style="cursor: pointer;"  >
        Full Download
      </div>
```

JS Code:

```
_test: function() {
  let checkBox = document.getElementById("checkboxFullDownload");

  if (checkBox.checked) {
    console.log("Checked");
    localStorage.setItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${this.item._id}`, "AllowFullDownload");
    checkBox.checked = true;
  }

  if (!checkBox.checked) {
    console.log("Unchecked");
    localStorage.removeItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${this.item._id}`);
    checkBox.checked = false;
  }
}
if (localStorage.getItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${_test.item._id}`) === "AllowFullDownload") {
    checkBox.checked = true;
    console.log("set to true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`let` keyword is block scope once declared in scope cannot be accessed outside of that scope.

In your case `let` keyword is in the scope of `_test: function(){}`. By moving it outside will do the work.

```
let checkBox = document.getElementById("checkboxFullDownload");
_test: function() {
  if (checkBox.checked) {
    console.log("Checked");
    localStorage.setItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${this.item._id}`, "AllowFullDownload");
    checkBox.checked = true;
  }

  if (!checkBox.checked) {
    console.log("Unchecked");
    localStorage.removeItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${this.item._id}`);
    checkBox.checked = false;
  }
}
if (localStorage.getItem(`${xmlTitle} ID:${_test.item._id}`) === "AllowFullDownload") {
    checkBox.checked = true;
    console.log("set to true");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wasn't the issue, the problem persists only when I add the "checked"

Comment: Where do you add the `check`?

Comment: In the _test function. I doubt it is the hoisting issue,  it is more likely related to the old framework I am working with. I re created a new post, you can take alook at it. Thanks